# Refactoring method parameter validation code to Contracts - inversion of statements problem

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, code-contracts

Old validation code is usually checking a boolean condition, and throws an exception if that is true.

Instead `Contract.Requires(...)` does the opposite (to pass the check we need to negate old condition).

I am refatoring old code and sometimes see some fairly advanced boolean statements, inversing them isn't that easy, and just doing `Contract.Requires(!(*old statements*))` appears bad and very confusing.

If it had something like `Contract.RequiresNot()` refactoring would be much more clear and straightforward here.

We also cannot add a static extension method. If someone encountered this problem and found some good solution I would like to hear it.

Comment: If they are complicated you should also try to break them up, at least at every &&.

Comment: well while I agree with you completely that it would be better, you have to agree with me that breaking appart boolean statements can be seen as an error source too. Its not that trivial at times. In some cases id rather not touch them, but still use Contracts instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could try leaving the old legacy validations in place and adding a [Contract.EndContractBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.endcontractblock.aspx) call immediately following the validations. From MSDN:

> Most code contains some parameter validation in the form of if-then-throw code. The contract tools recognize these statements as preconditions in the following cases:
>
> - The statements appear before any other statements in a method.
> - The entire set of such statements is followed by an explicit [Contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.aspx) method call, such as a call to the [Requires](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.requires.aspx), [Ensures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.ensures.aspx), [EnsuresOnThrow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.ensuresonthrow.aspx), or [EndContractBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.endcontractblock.aspx) method.
>
> When if-then-throw statements appear in this form, the tools recognize them as legacy requires statements. If no other contracts follow the if-then-throw sequence, end the code with the [Contract.EndContractBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.endcontractblock.aspx) method.
>
> ```
> if ( x == null ) throw new ...
> Contract.EndContractBlock(); // All previous "if" checks are preconditions
> ```
>
> Note that the condition in the preceding test is a negated precondition. (The actual precondition would be x != null.) A negated precondition is highly restricted: It must be written as shown in the previous example; that is, it should contain no else clauses, and the body of the then clause must be a single throw statement. The if test is subject to both purity and visibility rules (see [Usage Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx#usage_guidelines)), but the throw expression is subject only to purity rules. However, the type of the exception thrown must be as visible as the method in which the contract occurs.

Comment: yes I did consider this when I reviewed available methods on Contracts class and I remember about it being suggested approach for legacy. However I can consider this kind of "refactoring" incomplete, single line contract statements are much better looking then if - throw. Its more of "no refactoring, just insert EndContractBlock" after old statements solution. Also about those restriction rules, they arent that natural, compared to method clarity of Contract.Requires... Ill give it a thought, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the result of `old statements` in to a boolean variable with a proper name. That would get rid of the pair of confusing parenthesis and also serve to self-document your code =)